# No handlers could be found for logger "myapp.lib"

Tags: python, django, logging

I just upgraded to Django 1.3 which brings it's own logging module. I did set up logging and it is working when the modules are accessed by Apache/mod_wsgi. But when I am working with the django shell, Logging does not work - I always get the infamous error "**No handlers could be found for logger 'myapp.lib'**" when working on the shell.

This is the logging-part of my settings.py:

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': True,
    'formatters': {
        'simple': {
            'format': '%(levelname)s %(message)s'
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'file': {
            'class': 'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
            'formatter': 'simple',
            'filename': '/var/log/myapp.log',
            'maxBytes': '4096',
            'backupCount': '5'
        },
        'console': {
            'level':'DEBUG',
            'class':'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'simple'
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'myapp.lib': {
            'handlers': ['file', 'console',],
            'level': 'INFO',
        },
    }
}
```

And this is the Python code causing the error:

```
import logging
l=logging.getLogger(__name__)
l.warn("foo")
```

Comment: Can you print the value of `__name__`?

Comment: Also, can you run `./manage.py shell` and then run: `from django.conf import settings; print settings.LOGGING['loggers']`

Comment: name is equal to "myapp.lib", I've also tried setting "myapp.lib" directly.  `print settings.LOGGING['loggers']` gives me
`{'myapp.lib': {'level': 'INFO', 'handlers': ['file', 'console']}}`

Comment: And I just noticed that Logging is working for accesses through the Webserver - only on the command line (`manage.py shell`) I am getting these errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To log from the django shell you would need to run:

```
import logging
l=logging.getLogger('myapp.lib')
l.warn("foo")
```

`__name__` is `__main__` at the shell.

Comment: Thanks, but this is not the issue. Executing this code on the shell gives me the same error.

Comment: I'm stumped then. I used your exact LOGGING config with django 1.3 and the above works perfectly. Are you sure that the shell is showing django 1.3?  No virtualenv issues going on?

Comment: Oh cr*p. My $PYTHON_PATH included an old copy of Django 1.2 from another project. Well, duh! Thanks for your suggestions.