# related to freebase library

Tags: python, freebase

I'm using freebase library to get the article. But it is not working.  I'm using this example. http://tinyurl.com/6ynwrbk  Can any one fix this error? thanks

```
import freebase
query = {
  "id": "/en/jimi_hendrix",
  "/common/topic/article": [{
    "text": {
      "maxlength": 400,
      "chars": None
    }
  }]
}
result = freebase.mqlread(query)
print (result)
##################################
```

Edit : Code Updated

Comment: You might kill me for asking you this, but have you tried defining 'null'?  Or what about 'none'?

Comment: He could define `null = None`, and it should work... but that would be a little odd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you are getting is MQL complaining that there is no such property "chars". It works in the queryeditor because you are using MQL Extensions, a feature that is not currently supported.

Freebase doesn't store topic descriptions along with the other data due to size issues, but you can use the new Text API to retrieve them by id:

https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1-sandbox/text/en/jimi_hendrix

The python library you are using does not support this new API, but you can find more details and documentation, including library support here:
http://wiki.freebase.com/wiki/ApiText

Answer (score 0):

python has no `null` keyword, instead it has `None` which is an object that represents a null-like value.

Also, the request in the link you posted appears to be json.  Python's `None` will be encoded as `null` in json.

Answer (score 0):

To solve your first problem, switch `null` with `None`.

To solve your second problem (in the comments), try (in your import/feature list):

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig()
```

Or, you can try a variant of the solution found **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5417350/no-handlers-could-be-found-for-logger-myapp-lib)**.

It might work.  I hope this helped.